# Multi-threaded Benchmark in Java

Tags: java, exception

I am doing a science fair project in which I am testing how much additional processing cores increase computing speed. This is the multi-core benchmark I have programmed so far, but there are problems. The "thread#.join();" lines all throw errors. Can someone help fix this? Keep in mind I am a beginner so can you please explain in very simple terms how to fix it or show me by putting the repaired code in your response. Here is what I have:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class SciFair 
{

    /**
     * Numa Robertson
     * 1/13/11
     * Science Fair 2011
     */

    public static String now(String dateFormat) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
        return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner dataIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat timeInSeconds = new DecimalFormat("##.###");

        System.out.println("Are you ready to begin the benchmark? ");
        String response = dataIn.nextLine();
        double endNum = 0;

        if(response.equals("Yes") || response.equals("yes") || response.equals("Ok") || response.equals("ok")) {

            System.out.println("Benchmark starting at " + SciFair.now("H:mm:ss:SSS") + ".");

            String startTimeHours = SciFair.now("H");
            String startTimeMinutes = SciFair.now("mm");
            String startTimeSeconds = SciFair.now("ss");
            String startTimeMilliseconds = SciFair.now("SSS");
            double startTimeHoursNumFormat = Double.valueOf(startTimeHours.trim()).doubleValue();
            double startTimeMinutesNumFormat = Double.valueOf(startTimeMinutes.trim()).doubleValue();
            double startTimeSecondsNumFormat = Double.valueOf(startTimeSeconds.trim()).doubleValue();
            double startTimeMillisecondsNumFormat = Double.valueOf(startTimeMilliseconds.trim()).doubleValue();
            double startHoursInSeconds = (startTimeHoursNumFormat * 3600);
            double startMinutesInSeconds = (startTimeMinutesNumFormat * 60);
            double startMillisecondsInSeconds = (startTimeMillisecondsNumFormat / 1000);
            double startTotalSeconds = (startHoursInSeconds + startMinutesInSeconds + startTimeSecondsNumFormat + startMillisecondsInSeconds);

            Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    double endNum = 0;
                    double num = 5832544225416546445465465465465465448412168546725.2655236355335649499923164684654345649874181221173246189579162421579584572121334216957951462175918894199993642446445548521652158975;

                    for(double numberRun = 0; numberRun <= 1666666660; numberRun++) {
                        endNum = endNum+((num * 58445246411658545558.458561435435385465146445641894984984651321616548946132131654984 + 26564.6351648941654984156 / 321654984616321654654984365.3216548974165416484 + 216541648165141654.23164584961321316546844651 * 65616484316541486541.1654484646546576746862468546576248645814668585145181 / 111.3216516543464545795479884754424759845 * 3467247954975472171276545789595.4721756147541715715157145715145714514748717521 / 31654688498445132154.3215449848489461531654 * 61654984132165465484464131321145644684.3164846434654648446546546465456465465414321165118547521569845258547566352544 / 32136546465434654654484843131.3164484151515121211554464547951126758178571454164175415417584175664) / 2431276251975915431326725157958456157321624621765419.4321672175951247316726451751487465462645754579517232172757497516373127651975167516715);    
                    }
                }
            };


            Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    double endNum = 0;
                    double num = 5832544225416546445465465465465465448412168546725.2655236355335649499923164684654345649874181221173246189579162421579584572121334216957951462175918894199993642446445548521652158975;

                    for(double numberRun = 0; numberRun <= 1666666660; numberRun++) {
                        endNum = endNum+((num * 58445246411658545558.458561435435385465146445641894984984651321616548946132131654984 + 26564.6351648941654984156 / 321654984616321654654984365.3216548974165416484 + 216541648165141654.23164584961321316546844651 * 65616484316541486541.1654484646546576746862468546576248645814668585145181 / 111.3216516543464545795479884754424759845 * 3467247954975472171276545789595.4721756147541715715157145715145714514748717521 / 31654688498445132154.3215449848489461531654 * 61654984132165465484464131321145644684.3164846434654648446546546465456465465414321165118547521569845258547566352544 / 32136546465434654654484843131.3164484151515121211554464547951126758178571454164175415417584175664) / 2431276251975915431326725157958456157321624621765419.4321672175951247316726451751487465462645754579517232172757497516373127651975167516715);    
                    }
                }
            };

            //Snip out a bunch of copy/paste thread implementations



            thread1.start();
            thread2.start();
            thread3.start();
            thread4.start();
            thread5.start();
            thread6.start();

            thread1.join();
            thread2.join();
            thread3.join();
            thread4.join();
            thread5.join();
            thread6.join();


            String endTimeHours = SciFair.now("H");
            String endTimeMinutes = SciFair.now("mm");
            String endTimeSeconds = SciFair.now("ss");
            String endTimeMilliseconds = SciFair.now("SSS");
            double endTimeHoursNumFormat = Double.valueOf(endTimeHours.trim()).doubleValue();
            double endTimeMinutesNumFormat = Double.valueOf(endTimeMinutes.trim()).doubleValue();
            double endTimeSecondsNumFormat = Double.valueOf(endTimeSeconds.trim()).doubleValue();
            double endTimeMillisecondsNumFormat = Double.valueOf(endTimeMilliseconds.trim()).doubleValue();
            double endHoursInSeconds = (endTimeHoursNumFormat * 3600);
            double endMinutesInSeconds = (endTimeMinutesNumFormat * 60);
            double endMillisecondsInSeconds = (endTimeMillisecondsNumFormat / 1000);
            double endTotalSeconds = (endHoursInSeconds + endMinutesInSeconds + endTimeSecondsNumFormat + endMillisecondsInSeconds);

            double elapsedTime = (endTotalSeconds - startTotalSeconds);

            System.out.println("\nThe benchmark is complete at " + SciFair.now("H:mm:ss:SSS") + ", and the end result is " + endNum + ".");
            System.out.println("\nThe benchmark was run in " + timeInSeconds.format(elapsedTime) + " seconds.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nPlease restart the program when you are ready to benchmark.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Telling us what the error is goes a long way toward finding an answer!

Comment: Not a solution for you, but a suggestion to make your results more accurate. You should look into using a Cyclic Barrier. It's essentially like a starting gate for all your threads. It would allow you to get all the threads up and running in parallel *before* you start the timer. That way, you aren't including the cost of Thread creation time in your measurements. This will give you a more accurate picture as to how threading scales.

Comment: @rfeak is almost right (CountDownLatch would be better), if you want to measure the time it takes to perform the calculations alone and not include any of the Thread creation/destruction time. I think both measures are quite valid and worthy results. I'm sure you will find the results of your benchmark quite interesting and maybe even counter intuitive. Best of luck with your science fair entry!

Comment: A much simpler and more accurate way to take the time is `long start = System.nanoTime();` and at the end `long time = System.nanoTime() - start;` It is atleast micro-second accurate and only two lines of code.

Comment: If the person is not ready to run the benchmark, why are they running it. I suggest you just run the benchmark whenever the program is run.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Thread#join() is throwing a checked exception and the compiler wants you to handle that exception. Checked exceptions are typically handled by either stating that your method/function can throw the exception or catching the exception.

In your specific case, since you are just writing a simple benchmarking application, the simplest solution is to just indicate that your code could throw the exception.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
```

An example of handling the exception would be something like this:

```
try {
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    thread3.join();
    thread4.join();
    thread5.join();
    thread6.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); //This is a best practice for handling the InterruptedException only
    logger.log("The thread has been interrupted and should now exit quickly and cleanly. Processing may be incomplete.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an ExecutorService.  I hope you will see it makes managing threads much easier.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
int threads = 6;

System.out.println("Benchmark starting at " + new Date());
long start = System.nanoTime();
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
    es.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // place your benchmark code here
        }
    });
es.shutdown();
es.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;

System.out.printf("%nThe benchmark is complete at " + new Date() + "%nThe benchmark was run in %.3f seconds.%n", time / 1e9);
}
```

I assume your *compile* error is that you are not handling InterruptedException. There is no need to catch InterruptedException as a) it shouldn't happen b) you can't do anything but log it.